# Reading a cell dirty state in Ext JS?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is it possible to know whether or not a cell is dirty (edited) in Ext JS knowing its position (row and column idx)

The documentation that I have found http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.data.Model.html#property-dirty allowed me to modify that state with the .set() method :

```
Ext.getCmp('grid').store.data.items[currentPosition.row].set(content, content,{
            dirty: false, commit: true
        });
```

However, I have not been able to find a way to read off that state with the row and column idx.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can identify if a cell is dirty (modified) by looking at the `modified` property in the `items`.

```
Ext.getCmp('grid').store.data.items[currentPosition.row].modified
```

Would give you an object of the modified cells within the currentPosition.row index

Comment: Tried that but it returns a null value